# How we set camera capture pic to right direction in android java

Tags: java, android, image, photo

When I take Picture from my mobile camera or chose from glary already taken by my mobile camera is turned to other direction when set on image view what I should do Please guide when retrieve this picture also retrieve in this direction//When I take Picture from my mobile camera or chose from glary already taken by my mobile camera is turned to other direction when set on image view what I should do Please guide when retrieve this picture also retrieve in this direction

```
final CharSequence[] options = { "Take Photo", "Choose from Gallery","Cancel" };
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(RegisterstudentActivity.this);
            builder.setTitle("Add Photo!");
            builder.setItems(options, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
                    if (options[item].equals("Take Photo"))
                    {

                        Intent takePicture = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                       // takePicture.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
                        startActivityForResult(takePicture, 0);
                    }
                    else if (options[item].equals("Choose from Gallery"))
                    {
                       /* Intent pickPhoto = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                                android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                        startActivityForResult(pickPhoto, 1);*/
                        Dexter.withActivity(RegisterstudentActivity.this)
                                .withPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                                .withListener(new PermissionListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onPermissionGranted(PermissionGrantedResponse permissionGrantedResponse) {
                                        Intent intent=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
                                        intent.setType("image/*");
                                        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,"Select profile pic"),1);
                                    }

                                    @Override
                                    public void onPermissionDenied(PermissionDeniedResponse permissionDeniedResponse) {

                                    }

                                    @Override
                                    public void onPermissionRationaleShouldBeShown(PermissionRequest permissionRequest, PermissionToken permissionToken) {
                                        permissionToken.continuePermissionRequest();
                                    }
                                }).check();
                    }
                    else if (options[item].equals("Cancel")) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                }
            });
            builder.show();

         //onactivity result
            @SuppressLint("LongLogTag")
          @Override
        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent imageReturnedIntent) 
              {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, imageReturnedIntent);
        switch (requestCode) {
           case 0:
       /* if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Bundle extras = imageReturnedIntent.getExtras();
            Bitmap imageBitmap = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
            sprofile.setImageBitmap(imageBitmap);

        }*/
        if (resultCode==RESULT_OK)
        {
            //new thing
            assert imageReturnedIntent != null;
            filepath=imageReturnedIntent.getData();
            try {
                InputStream inputStream=getContentResolver().openInputStream(filepath);
                Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
                sprofile.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

            }catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }
        }

        break;
       case 1:
     /*   if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Uri selectedImage = imageReturnedIntent.getData();
            sprofile.setImageURI(selectedImage);
        }*/
        if (requestCode==1 && resultCode==RESULT_OK)
        {
            //new thing
            assert imageReturnedIntent != null;
            filepath=imageReturnedIntent.getData();
            try {
                InputStream inputStream=getContentResolver().openInputStream(filepath);
                Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
                sprofile.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

            }catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }
        }
        break;
       }
      }
```

[image]

After set on Image view

[image]

Comment: try to add `android:scaleType="centerCrop"` in your imageView

Comment: I have already uses but no result